# fetch image to be placed on imageview from crud func

Tags: swift, core-data, fetch, crud, binary-data

In my Swift code I have a CRUD func that saves binary data. I would like to fetch the 2nd item in the binary set of core data. I have all of the code and a photo of my core data attributes and entities. The error I am getting at the line:

```
resultImages = DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.fetchImagesByID(id: 2)
```

is:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Picture' to type '[Picture]'

Code:

```
import UIKit


import Foundataion
import CoreData


extension Picture {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Picture> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Picture>(entityName: "Picture")
    }

    @NSManaged public var pic: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: Int64

}

extension Picture : Identifiable {

}

extension Date {
    static var currentTimeStamp: Int64{
        return Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
}

import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DataBaseHelper {
    
    // MARK: - Get Context
    
    class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext{
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    static let shareInstance = DataBaseHelper()
        
    let context = getContext()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Picture")
    
    // MARK: - Save Images
    
    func saveImage(picString: String, id: Int64 = Date.currentTimeStamp) {

// here I have passed id = Date.currentTimeStamp, as we need unique ID for each of our object in coreData and Date.currentTimeStamp will always give unique integer. we will use this ID to update and delete particular object.
        
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Picture", in: context)!
        
        let image = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)
                
        image.setValue(picString, forKey: "pic") // key should be same as the attributes taken in coreData Table.
        image.setValue(id, forKey: "id") // key should be same as the attributes taken in coreData Table.
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Images saved in coreData")
            print("imageString: \(picString), id: \(id)") // this will print your entered (saved) object in coreData
        }  catch let error {
            print("Could not save images: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - fetch Images
    
    func fetchImages() -> [Picture] {
        
        var arrImages = [Picture]()
        
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        
        do {
            arrImages = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Picture] ?? [Picture]()
            print("Images while fetching from coreData: \(arrImages)") // this will print all objects saved in coreData in an array form.
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not fetch images: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return arrImages
    }
    
    // MARK: - fetch Images by ID
    func fetchImageBy(id: Int64) -> Picture? {
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == \(id)")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        
        do {
            let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return result.first as? Picture
        } catch {
            print("Unable to fetch picture for ID \(id): \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
    func fetchImagesByID(id: Int64) -> Picture {

        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults =  false
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id == \(id)")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

        let result = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return result?.first as? Picture ?? Picture()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Update Image
    
    func updateImage(object: Picture) {
        
        let image = fetchImagesByID(id: object.id) // we will first fetch object by its ID then update it.
        
        image.pic = object.pic
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Image updated in CoreData")
            print("after updating Picture --> \(object)")
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not update Picture: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Delete Image
    
    func deleteImage(id: Int64) {
        
        let image = fetchImagesByID(id: id) // we will first fetch object by its ID then delete it.
        
        context.delete(image)
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Image deleted from CoreData")
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not delete Image --> \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var  btnSaveImages = UIButton()
    
    var btnShowImages = UIButton()
    
    
    var pic = UIImageView()
    
    
    var resultImages = [Picture]() // this an an instance of our model class (coreData)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.navigationItem.title = "CoreData Demo"
        saveImagesInCoreData()
        [ pic,btnSaveImages,btnShowImages].forEach {
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.5...0.7),
                green: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.3...0.5),
                alpha: 1
            )
            
            $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
            
            if let textfield = $0 as? UITextField {
                
                textfield.textAlignment = .center
            }
            
            if let label = $0 as? UILabel {
                
                label.textAlignment = .center
            }
        }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pic.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
        pic.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            pic.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            pic.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            btnSaveImages.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pic.bottomAnchor),
            btnSaveImages.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            btnSaveImages.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            btnSaveImages.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            
            btnShowImages.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btnSaveImages.bottomAnchor),
            btnShowImages.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.10, constant: 0),
            btnShowImages.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            btnShowImages.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        
        ])
        
        btnShowImages.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnShowImages_Event), for: .touchDown)
        btnShowImages.setTitle("show", for: .normal)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Save Images
    
    func saveImagesInCoreData() {
        
        // I have added 4 images in Assets folder, here we will save 3 images in CoreData
        
        let image1 = "flower1"
        let image2 = "flower2"
        let image3 = "flower3"
        
        DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.saveImage(picString: image1)
        DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.saveImage(picString: image2)
        DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.saveImage(picString: image3)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Fetch Images
    
    func fetchImagesFromCoreData() {
        if let picture = DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.fetchImageBy(id:  1) {
            print("one")
           // pic.image = picture.pic
            

            resultImages = [picture]
            
        } else {
            print("two")
            resultImages = []
        }
      //  resultImages = DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.fetchImagesByID(id: 2) // this will give fetched images
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Set Up TableView
    
    func setUpTableView () {
     
    }
    
    // MARK: - Button Save Images Event

    @IBAction func btnSaveImages_Event(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        saveImagesInCoreData() // save images in CoreData
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Button Show Images Event
    
    @objc func btnShowImages_Event(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        fetchImagesFromCoreData() // fetch Images from CoreData
      
    }
}

// MARK: - Extesnion TableViewDelegate and TableViewDataSource

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return resultImages.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell") ?? UITableViewCell()
        
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: resultImages[indexPath.row].pic ?? "")
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        
        return true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        
        let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Edit") { (action, indexPath) in
            print("Action Edit")
            
            // here we will edit image of selected row in our tableView, we will update selected row with new image that is "flower4".
            
            let image4 = "flower4"
            
            self.resultImages[indexPath.row].pic = image4
            
            DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.updateImage(object: self.resultImages[indexPath.row]) // update image of selected row in tableView
         
                                    
        }
        
       
        
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
            print("Action Delete")
            
            // here we will delete an object of selected row in our tableView.
            
            DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.deleteImage(id: self.resultImages[indexPath.row].id) // delete object of selected row in tableView
            self.resultImages.remove(at: indexPath.row) // remove from resultImages array
         
        }
        
        return [deleteAction, editAction]
        
    }
    
}
```

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4qPY.png)

Comment: The error says that you’re trying to assign a single `Picture` to a variable that’s declared to be an array of `Picture`, in this case `resultImages`.

Comment: here resultImages is an array of Picture that is [Picture]. and func fetchImagesByID(id: Int64) -> Picture this will give you a single object of Picture. so you are assigning a single object Picture to an array of [Picture], which is wrong

Comment: if you want to fetch a single object then you should declare a variable of Picture not an array, for example var objectPic: Picture? , and then you can assign objectPic = DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.fetchImagesByID(id: 2)

Comment: by the way, you won't get result for id = 2, as you have passed timeStamp as an id, and timeStamp will give you an id like id = 1673875246228 something like this, so id = 2 will give you zero result, if you want to manually add id then in save function don't pass default value of id, and while saving images you will be able to add id manually

Comment: objectPic = DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.fetchImagesByID(id: 1673875246228)
        
            imagePlace.image = objectPic does not work causes error Cannot assign value of type 'Picture?' to type 'UIImage?'